# Python, read from file -> add file content to list -> compare list to user input

Tags: python, file-io

Ok so as the title states am retrieving a word from a txt file then adding it to a list then am trying to compare the content of the list to user input.

```
X = []
Y = open(‘file.txt’,’r’)
X.append(Y.read())
Z = input(‘I’)
A = X[0]
if Z == A:
    print(‘y’)
```

I’ve compared types and they match, have tried python 2&3 and nothing. I’ve also tried with a preset array and it works fine. I’ve tried to separate halves into functions and still no.

Repr gives:
List = ‘a\n’
Input = ‘a’

Comment: `“` and `”` are not valid quotes, and `If` should be lower case.

Comment: Try printing the `repr` of your strings to see what the differences are. Probably whitespace.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: What is repr, and how is it used

Comment: `print(repr(Z))` and `print(repr(A))` and see what the differences are. `repr` is described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

Comment: Also, please correct the errors I pointed out in my first comment. Your code as you've given it does not produce the problem you are describing because it is unrunnable.

Comment: Errors corrected

Comment: `‘` and `’` are _also_ not valid quotes, and `If` should still be lower case.

Comment: Sorry I typed this on my phone, maybe your seeing something I can’t. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are reading from a file has a new line at the end.

You can easily remove it using [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) (remove surrounding whitespace) or [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) (remove trailing whitespace).

For example:

```
if Z == A.strip():
    print("y")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read().strip()

user_input = input('Please enter something: ')

if user_input == data:
    print('Correct!')
else:
    print('FALSE')
```